# How to add custom function to response object in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my API-application I have a fixed response for errors in different parts. As you can see `res.status(400).json({"error": "Invalid input"})` is repeating a lot, in different files and modules actually.

I could create module-function `invalidInput(res)`, which will eliminate duplication, but I really want this to be global part of `res` object, like `res.invalidInput()`.

How could I make it in JS/Node.JS?

```
router.get("/users", function(req, res) {
    // ...
    if (error) {
        return res.status(400).json({"error": "Invalid input"});
    }
});

router.get("/items", function(req, res) {
    // ...
    if (error) {
        return res.status(400).json({"error": "Invalid input"});
    }
});

// etc
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use your own custom middleware. Add this somewhere above your route handler:

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.invalidInput = function() {
        return res.status(400).json({"error": "Invalid input"});
    };
    next();
});
```

and then you can do `res.invalidInput()` in your route handlers.

Comment: Will this method reduce performance.? due to creating a new function for each request and attache to the response object. I am doing same with 12 functions attaching to response. What could other best way to improve performance?

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this code and its worked for me:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    /**
     * (default status 200)
     * Success response
     */
    res.success = function ({result={}, code=200, message=""}) {
        return res.json({
            result,
            code,
            message
        })
    }

    /**
     * Custom error response
     */
    res.error = function({errors={}, code=400, message="", result={}}) {
        return res.json({
            errors,
            code,
            message,
            result
        })
    }

    /**
     * (status 403)
     * Bad request response
     */
    res.badreq = function({errors={}, code=400, message="", result={}}) {
        return res.status(400).error({ errors, code, message, result })
    }

    /**
     * (status 403)
     * Forbidden request response
     */
    res.forbidden = function({errors={}, code=403, message="", result={}}) {
        return res.status(403).error({ errors, code, message, result })
    }
    
    /**
     * (status 401)
     * Unauthorize request response
     */
    res.unauth = function({errors={}, code=401, message="", result={}}) {
        return res.status(403).error({ errors, code, message, result })
    }

    /**
     * (status 500)
     * Internal request response
     */
    res.internal = function({errors={}, code=500, message="", result={}}) {
        return res.status(500).error({ errors, code, message, result })
    }

    next()
})
```