# How can I add a custom value to my Node.js HTTP request for Express to consume

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an Express server listening on a Unix Domain Socket. I'm making an http request like so:

```
const requestOptions = {socketPath, method, path, headers, _custom: {foo: () => 'bar'}}
http.request(requestOptions, responseCb)
```

And want to use `_custom` in my Express route handlers

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req._custom)
})
```

Is this possible?

EDIT: `_custom` is an object with functions.

EDIT: The answer I marked as correct is the best solution I could find, however it does not allow sending of objects (which is what I really want).

Comment: Where do you expect `_custom` to be placed in the HTTP request? You're going to want to add it as a custom header - something like `X-My-Header`, where `X-` signifies something is non-standard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add custom function to response object in Node.JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113590/how-to-add-custom-function-to-response-object-in-node-js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `_custom` to your `req` object by adding custom [middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) in your Express server prior to your routes that need to use `req._custom`.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {

  if (req.get('X-Custom-Header')) {
   // add custom to your request object
   req._custom = req.get('X-Custom-Header');
  } 

  return next();
});
```

On the client side you can add the custom header

```
let headers = {
  'X-Custom-Header': 'my-custom-value'
};

const requestOptions = {socketPath, method, path, headers};
http.request(requestOptions, responseCb)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what I'm currently doing, but I added clarification to my question: `_custom` is an object. Currently I'm using `JSON.stringify`, but ideally I want to pass the object itself which has functions. Using `stringify` I lose those functions and other context. Obviously in a normal HTTP request you cannot pass an object in this way, but I was hoping it was possible given these constraints (the request is made on the same server as the Express app and is made over Unix Domain Socket).

Comment: I'm not sure that is a safe thing to do, wouldn't you just be exposing yourself to JS Injection because you would need to use `eval()` on the stringified JS function?

Comment: This does not operate on user input, so no concern with js injection. What I _really_ want is to pass the entire object as-is (without stringify) to maintain execution context.

Comment: @Brett What you want is not possible as-is because Unix domain socket, just like HTTP requests, only transfer bytes. However if you are willing to develop your own serialization system you can do whatever you want but that is entirely up to you. You can serialize functions for example by using the `toString()` method. You'd have to invent your own protocol though. Also be warned that you probably won't be able to serialize functions implemented in C/C++ like `document.getElementById()` or `btoa()` etc