# Could not access properties to req.query object in expressjs

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have a router:

```
router.get('/top-5-cheap', aliasTopTours, getAllTours);
```

And middlewares:

1. Middleware `aliasTopTours`:

Here I want to add some properties: `req.query.limit`, `req.query.sort`, `req.query.fields`

```
import { Response, Request, NextFunction } from 'express';

const aliasTopTours = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  req.query.limit = '5';
  req.query.sort = '-ratingsAverage,price';
  req.query.fields = 'name,price,ratingsAverage,summary,difficulty';
  next();
};

export { aliasTopTours };
```

2. Middleware `getAllTours`:
   I could not access properties on `req.query`:

```
const getAllTours = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  console.log(req.query.limit); // undefined
  console.log(req.query.sort); // undefined
  console.log(req.query.fields); // undefined
  res.end('tours');
}
```

How could I add custom properties on the object `req.query` in a middleware programmatically
and access them in another middleware?

It works perfectly in JavaScript version:

```
const aliasTopTours = (req, res, next) => {
  req.query.limit = '5';
  console.log(req.query.limit); // 5
  next();
};
```

TypeScript version (NOT working)

```
const aliasTopTours = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  // not working
  req.query.limit = '5';
  console.log(req.query.limit); // undefined
  next();
};
```

It seems like it does not allow to add the property limit to the object `req.query`.

Any help with TS version?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63538665/how-to-type-request-query-in-express-using-typescript

Comment: @colinD No. It never works.

Comment: what do you get when you log the variable ```req```? you can try with ```console.dir(req, depth: null);```

Comment: I log `console.log(req.query)` and the output is `[Object: null prototype] {}`

Answer (score 0):

In express you should add your own custom values to the `req` object. This also makes sense from the point of view that the request, in your case the query params, are not changed by this. This could be problematic if, for example, the requester enters a value in the query param and this is immediately overwritten in the middleware. With a large code base, this can lead to long unwanted debugging sessions.

Here we can certainly discuss subobjects like `req._custom`. But in my opinion this is currently not part of the question. In any case, it is not my way to implement this.

This has also been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39839354/how-can-i-add-a-custom-value-to-my-node-js-http-request-for-express-to-consume) before.

Another example can be found in the [Express specification](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) under the point **Middleware function requestTime**.

Here the Javascript snippet from there.

```js
const requestTime = function (req, res, next) {
  req.requestTime = Date.now()
  next()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But is there a way to achieve my problem?